# YouTube API bug - commentThreads.list not working, error 404

Tags: php, multithreading, api, youtube, comments

I'm working on an application in PHP using Google YouTube API.

There seems to be a bug in the commentThreads.list resource.
Even the example code on Google developer site for PHP is broken.
( do they even run these scripts before posting ? :-\  this is the
4th script on their site under their examples that is broken not working code.
I have fixed all the other problems myself, but for some reason every time I try, or use an example script I get error 404 back.

Here is the section of code causing the problem.

```
// Call the YouTube Data API's commentThreads.list method to retrieve video comment threads.
$videoComments = $youtube->commentThreads->listCommentThreads('snippet', array(
    'videoId' => $VIDEO_ID,
    'textFormat' => 'plainText',
));
```

and here is the error it produces.

=================================================

```
A service error occurred: Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet: (404) The specified comment thread could not be found. Check the value of the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#id">id</a></code> property in the request body to ensure that it is correct.
```

=================================================

but the $VIDEO_ID is good, and works in the script prior to this block of code.

Why can't the comments list for the video be found ?
This fatal error stops the script.

any suggestions ? thanks in advance.